# Reactive Picker Input, Default Configuration Visitor's First Visit

Tags: shiny, shiny-server, shiny-reactivity

I am building a shiny app with that contains a reactive picker input. My reactive picker input works well as soon as a visitor selects a period (i.e., it shows in the menu `Select Country` the relevant countries for this period). However when a visitor first visits the App, `Select Country` proposes all possible options although it should only show the ones that are relevant for the default period (i.e., `selected = period1`).

In other words, how can I ensure that the reactive picker input also updates when a visitor first visits the App?

Thank you!

Below is a reproducible example. If you run this code and then click on `Select Country` you will see that all three countries are available. Now if you run the code and then click on `Period`, select `Period 2: X to Y` , then select `Period 1: X to Z`, and then click on `Select Country` you will see that only `UK` and `USA` are available which is the expected behavior!

```
choice_name <- c('UK','USA','BE','BE')
choice_id <- c(1, 2, 3,3)
period <- c('period1', 'period1', 'period3', 'period3')
data <- data.frame(choice_name, choice_id, period)

choices_picker <- unique(data$choice_id)
names(choices_picker) <- unique(data$choice_name)


ui <- bootstrapPage(                
  absolutePanel(left = 10, bottom = 10, draggable = TRUE, 
  selectInput(inputId = "input_period", label = "Period",
    choices = c("Period 1: X to Z" = "period1", "Period 2: X to Y" = "period2", "Period 3: X to X" = "period3"),
    selected = "period1"),
  pickerInput(inputId = "picker_cty",
    label = "Select Country",
    choices = choices_picker,
    multiple = TRUE),
))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  # Reactive pickerInput ---------------------------------
  observeEvent(input$input_period, {
    
    data1 <- data[data$period == input$input_period,]
    datau <- unique(data$choice_id)
    data1u <- unique(data1$choice_id)
    
    disabled_choices <- ifelse(datau %in% data1u, 0,1)
    
    # Generate reactive picker input
    updatePickerInput(session = session, 
                      inputId = "picker_cty",
                      choices = choices_picker,
                      choicesOpt = list(
                        disabled = disabled_choices,
                        style = ifelse(disabled_choices,
                                       yes = "color: rgba(119, 119, 119, 0.5);",
                                       no = "")
                      ))
  }, ignoreInit = TRUE)
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `ignoreNULL=FALSE` in

```
 observeEvent(input$input_period, {
    ...
  }, ignoreNULL=FALSE)
```